# js code runs and then refreshes quickly i cannot notice the changes more than a second after running the code

Tags: javascript, frontend

https://github.com/Ahmedalzarka/pod-request-access-landing-page:

```js
let requestBtn = document.getElementById("requestbtn")
let oops = document.querySelector(".oops")

requestBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let emailInput = document.getElementById("email").value
  emailInput == "" ? oops.classList.remove("hidden") : null
})
```

```css
:root {
  font-size: 10px;
  --font-heading: 5.2em;
  --font-paragraph: 18px;
  --green-color: #54E6AF;
  --form-color: #2C344B;
  --background-navy-blue-color: #121725;
  --white: #ffffff;
  --form-hover-color: #5A668A;
  --grey-color: #C2CBE5;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Chivo', sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding-bottom: 130px;
  background-color: var(--background-navy-blue-color);
}

body::before {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-image: url(../assets/desktop/bg-pattern-dots.svg), url(../assets/desktop/image-host.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right bottom 10%, right center;
}

body::after {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-image: url(../assets/desktop/logo.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left 20% top 10%;
}

main {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10%;
  transform: translateY(-40%);
  max-width: fit-content;
  padding: 90px 60px 0 0;
  background-color: var(--background-navy-blue-color);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main h1 {
  font-size: 5.2em;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 62px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: var(--green-color);
}

main h1 span {
  color: var(--grey-color);
}

main p {
  max-width: 445px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: var(--grey-color);
  opacity: 0.5;
  margin-top: 24px;
}

form {
  margin-top: 40px;
  position: relative;
  width: 430px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 32px;
  background-color: var(--form-color);
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

button {
  color: black;
  height: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 8px;
  padding: 10px 28px;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: var(--green-color);
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #B3FFE2;
}

.img-contianer {
  margin-top: 42px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 40px;
}

.img-contianer img {
  object-fit: contain;
}

.oops {
  color: #FB3E3E;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 0;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 1250px) {
  body::after {
    background-size: 200px;
    background-position: left 40px top 50px;
  }
  body::before {
    background-image: url(../assets/desktop/bg-pattern-dots.svg), url(../assets/tablet/image-host.jpg);
    background-position: left 5% bottom, right top;
  }
  main {
    left: 0;
  }
  main h1 {
    font-size: 48px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  body::after {
    background-position: center top 10%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  body::before {
    background-image: url(../assets/mobile/image-host.jpg);
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  main {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0 24px;
    background-color: transparent;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  main h1 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  main p {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .container {
    align-items: center;
  }
  .img-contianer {
    order: 2;
    gap: 10px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0.8;
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
  form {
    order: 3;
  }
  button {
    width: 100%;
    position: static;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin-top: 16px;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Publish your podcasts<br><span>everywhere</span>.</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Upload your audio to Pod with a single click. We’ll then distribute your podcast to Spotify, Apple Podcasts, Google Podcasts, Pocket Casts and more!</p>
    <form>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email address" id="email">
      <button id="requestbtn">Request Access</button>
    </form>
    <p class="oops hidden">Oops! Please check your email</p>
    <div class="img-contianer">
      <img src="assets/desktop/spotify.svg" alt="spotify">
      <img src="assets/desktop/apple-podcast.svg" alt="apple-podcast">
      <img src="assets/desktop/google-podcasts.svg" alt="google">
      <img src="assets/desktop/pocket-casts.svg" alt="pocket">
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

[image]

[image]

The hidden message "oops....." shows and hides in the same second.

I don't know what to do.

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve] _not as images_. You can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the question edit toolbar to help you.

Comment: It sounds like your form is submitting, and you're asking how to prevent form submission if it fails validation, which you should google for.

Answer (score 1):

1. The button missing the type attribute won't know to submit the form when button is clicked.

```html
<button type="submit" id="requestbtn">Request Access</button>
```

2. To account for button pressed or user pressing enter on the email field, suggestion to add event listener to form.
3. To prevent form submission on error, use `event.preventDefault()`

```js
const requestAccessForm = document.getElementById("requestAccessForm");
let requestBtn = document.getElementById("requestbtn");
let oops = document.querySelector(".oops")


requestAccessForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  let emailInput = document.getElementById("email");
  
  if (emailInput.value === "") {
    oops.classList.remove("hidden");
    
    console.log("invalid email");
    // Will prevent form from submitting
    event.preventDefault();
    
  } else {
    // else statement just for testing
    console.log("form will submit");
  }
});
```

```js
const requestAccessForm = document.getElementById("requestAccessForm");
let requestBtn = document.getElementById("requestbtn");
let oops = document.querySelector(".oops")


requestAccessForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  let emailInput = document.getElementById("email");
  
  if (emailInput.value === "") {
    oops.classList.remove("hidden");
    
    console.log("invalid email");
    // Will prevent form from submitting
    event.preventDefault();
    
  } else {
    // else statement just for testing
    console.log("form will submit");
  }
});
```

```css
:root {
  font-size: 10px;
  --font-heading: 5.2em;
  --font-paragraph: 18px;
  --green-color: #54E6AF;
  --form-color: #2C344B;
  --background-navy-blue-color: #121725;
  --white: #ffffff;
  --form-hover-color: #5A668A;
  --grey-color: #C2CBE5;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Chivo', sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding-bottom: 130px;
  background-color: var(--background-navy-blue-color);
}

body::before {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-image: url(../assets/desktop/bg-pattern-dots.svg), url(../assets/desktop/image-host.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right bottom 10%, right center;
}

body::after {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-image: url(../assets/desktop/logo.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left 20% top 10%;
}

main {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10%;
  transform: translateY(-40%);
  max-width: fit-content;
  padding: 90px 60px 0 0;
  background-color: var(--background-navy-blue-color);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main h1 {
  font-size: 5.2em;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 62px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: var(--green-color);
}

main h1 span {
  color: var(--grey-color);
}

main p {
  max-width: 445px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: var(--grey-color);
  opacity: 0.5;
  margin-top: 24px;
}

form {
  margin-top: 40px;
  position: relative;
  width: 430px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 32px;
  background-color: var(--form-color);
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

button {
  color: black;
  height: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 8px;
  padding: 10px 28px;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: var(--green-color);
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #B3FFE2;
}

.img-contianer {
  margin-top: 42px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 40px;
}

.img-contianer img {
  object-fit: contain;
}

.oops {
  color: #FB3E3E;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 0;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 1250px) {
  body::after {
    background-size: 200px;
    background-position: left 40px top 50px;
  }
  body::before {
    background-image: url(../assets/desktop/bg-pattern-dots.svg), url(../assets/tablet/image-host.jpg);
    background-position: left 5% bottom, right top;
  }
  main {
    left: 0;
  }
  main h1 {
    font-size: 48px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  body::after {
    background-position: center top 10%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  body::before {
    background-image: url(../assets/mobile/image-host.jpg);
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  main {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0 24px;
    background-color: transparent;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  main h1 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  main p {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .container {
    align-items: center;
  }
  .img-contianer {
    order: 2;
    gap: 10px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0.8;
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
  form {
    order: 3;
  }
  button {
    width: 100%;
    position: static;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin-top: 16px;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Publish your podcasts<br><span>everywhere</span>.</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Upload your audio to Pod with a single click. We’ll then distribute your podcast to Spotify, Apple Podcasts, Google Podcasts, Pocket Casts and more!</p>
    <form id="requestAccessForm">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email address" id="email">
      <button type="submit" id="requestbtn">Request Access</button>
    </form>
    <p class="oops hidden">Oops! Please check your email</p>
    <div class="img-contianer">
      <img src="assets/desktop/spotify.svg" alt="spotify">
      <img src="assets/desktop/apple-podcast.svg" alt="apple-podcast">
      <img src="assets/desktop/google-podcasts.svg" alt="google">
      <img src="assets/desktop/pocket-casts.svg" alt="pocket">
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a form tag, u need to be careful to the buttons, cause by default in a form they are `type="submit"`, and this cause the page to refresh every time they are clicked.

To fix the problem just specify the button type like so:

```
<button type="button" id="requestbtn">Request Access</button>
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

As [Edoardo Balducci mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76194160/13561410), buttons are [`type="submit"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#type) by default. This means, clicking the button will try to submit its associated form.

Since the input field is not [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required), it is optional. Because it is the form's only form control, **the form is always valid and will always submit** when requested (here: clicking the button).

To prevent submission, try (one of) the following:

- Make the input field `required`.
- Conditionally prevent the click from submitting the form (by calling [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)).
- Change the button to `type="button"`, and conditionally submit the form manually (e.g. by calling [`form.requestSubmit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit))

---

As [Arty.Simon mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76194510/13561410), it would be better to listen to a [`submit` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) on the form. This better conveys intent and also handles form submission requests originating from elsewhere than the button.